# Using Alamofire calling JSONArray

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm still beginner in iOS development. I'm using Swift 3, Alamofire 4 and `SwiftyJson` for my project. I try to fetch the data from JSON. JSON return in single array. Here is the return :

**JSON :**

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "post_title": "Event_1",
    "post_content": "Taylor Swift",
    "start_date": "2016-11-23",
    "end_date": "2016-11-23",
    "post_date": "2016-11-18"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "post_title": "Event_2",
    "post_content": "Nickelback",
    "start_date": "2016-11-15",
    "end_date": "2016-11-16",
    "post_date": "2016-11-15"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "post_title": "Event_3",
    "post_content": "Nirvana",
    "start_date": "10.00pm on 22-02-2012",
    "end_date": "6.00am on 23-02-2012",
    "post_date": "2016-07-10"
}]
```

**Swift :**

```
var newsArray : [[String:Any]] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let currentNews = newsArray[indexPath.row]
    if let post_content = currentNews["post_content"] {
        cell.lbl_content.text = post_content as? String
    }

    return cell
}    


func getJSON(){

    Alamofire.request(BASE_URL).responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)

            if let tempArray = json as? [[String: Any]] {
                self.newsArray = tempArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue :**

> Looks like tempArray don't hold any value.

I try to implement the value in tableViewCell.

Any help is appreciated and many thanks.

Comment: Print the tempArray you will get idea whether array is empty or not

Comment: yes, and its empty

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL).responseJSON {
    response in

    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        //to get JSON return value
        if let result = response.result.value {
            let JSON = result as! [[String: Any]]
            //then use guard to get the value your want

        }

case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```

}

Comment: Why its return all the value in jsonArray instead of jsonObject ?

Comment: And 1 more thing, why you are not using (let **value**) ?

Comment: "Why its return all the value in jsonArray instead of jsonObject ? " - I dont know either, it depends on your server implementation, I read your json which doesnt have a key in the root level, so i determine that is a jsonArray.

Comment: "And 1 more thing, why you are not using (let value) ?" - You mean why I use guard in stead of let? guard is a swift syntax, please read this http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/

Comment: Correct, the json dont have a key at root level. What is the difference between `response.result.value` and `value` ?
Looks like you're getting the value from the parameter.

Comment: oh for that part, I just copy my code into your code block, so I didnt notice the let value your declared. So how is it going? still fixing it?

Comment: I manage to fix it, 1 more thing, do u use swiftyJSON in your projects ?

Comment: glad to know make it. With more experience, you will be able to disguise json array and json object quickly. I do not use SwiftyJSON, i know it is a hot repo on Github. happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if let tempArray = json as? [[String: Any]] {
                self.newsArray = tempArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Use `json` only don't `json[]`

Comment: what is the value of 
 print(json)?

Comment: same like return in JSON at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Below

```
if let tempArray = json as? [[String: Any]] {
                self.newsArray = tempArray.mutableCopy()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Comment: It error. **Value of type [[String:Any]] has no member 'mutableCopy'**

Answer (score 0):

Try change `json[] as? [[String: Any]]` to `json.array`

Comment: It error : **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[JSON]'**

Comment: then change `arrayValue` to `array` only, its just for checking nil

Answer (score 0):

```
var newsArray : [[String:Any]] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let currentNews = newsArray[indexPath.row]
    if let post_content = currentNews["post_content"] {
        cell.lbl_content.text = post_content as? String
    }

    return cell
}    
    func getJSON(){

    Alamofire.request(BASE_URL).responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)

            if let tempArray = json as? NSArray {
                self.newsArray = tempArray
                print(tempArray)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
    }
```

Try above line of code. May help you.

Comment: No value on tempArray

Comment: print log of print(json)?

Comment: on print(json) has value, but when it comes to print(tempArray) is null

Comment: can you paste it here?

Comment: `'NSArray' is not convertible to '[[String:Any]]'` so I change to to `self.newsArray = tempArray as! [[String:Any]]`. After that, the `tempArray` still no value.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm not using Swift 3, Alamofire 4. I have found some solution in the below link. Please check, if you can any solution from this. 
Link: http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/10/how-to-use-alamofire-and-swiftyjson-with-swift/

```
Alamofire.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

         let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

        if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
            self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        }
        if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
            self.tblJSON.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the **contacts** not exist, what I should I put ?

Comment: @Sendra please try to use this:  if let resData = swiftyJsonVar.arrayObject